# Virtual Machine and IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I am using VirtualBox to run a Ubuntu 11.04 Server as a guest OS. However, using NAT the VM get's a private IP.

I want my guest oses to get their own IP on the network the host is on. I.E., my host's IP is 192.168.10.109, I want the guest to be 192.168.10.110 instead of 10.?.?.?.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to assign what is called a Bridged Adapter. In the main VirtualBox window, select the VM you want to work with and click the Settings icon. In the settings window, go to Network, and you will see the Settings page for "Adapter 1" Change "Attached to:" to "Bridged" and you should be good to go.

Here's a graphic of what you need to do (change #4 to Bridged):
[image]

Comment: +1 for screenshots =)

Answer (score 4):

It's called "bridged" network. Change the network settings for the VM.